# how watch to change angularjs model which checkbox changed from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I use https://github.com/Dimox/jQueryFormStyler for styling form inputs.

I set the property `ng-model="c.model.acept"`.

If I click on "styled checkbox", then input gets to property "checked", but the angular model still has the old value.

I tried to trigger the `change` event with no result.

If I trigger the `click` event, then the checkbox gets changed twice (once from click, and then the second time from the triggered `click` event).

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3wo74jdk/30/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11994/

I guess this must be an issue with JQuery loaded first. Here is an example with just AngularJS and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Your script doesn't have jQueryFormStyler. I know that it work fine without jQueryFormStyler. Site is developed with jQueryFormStyler and i can't remove it from site disign :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not change "ng-model" of particular input field conditionally.
In this condition what you can do is, keep two input field and use "ng-show" or "ng-if" attribute to show & hide input field conditionally.

Hope this will hep you.